# Error with non matching type: Option<&[u8]> and Option<&[u8;32]>

Tags: rust

I playing with the Rust code, and I've got to a place in which I have a problem with converting `Option<&[u8; 32]>` to `Option<&[u8]>`.

A (very) simplified example:

```rust
pub type Foo = [u8; 32];

fn fun_one(inp: Option<&[u8]>) {
    println!("{:?}", inp);
}

fn fun_two(x: Option<&Foo>) {
    fun_one(x)
}

fn main() {
    let x = [11u8; 32];
    fun_two(Some(&x));
}
```

Link: [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=e80ff335fb164cabe18bad6916f4cf82)

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:8:13
  |
8 |     fun_one(x)
  |             ^ expected slice `[u8]`, found array `[u8; 32]`
  |
  = note: expected enum `Option<&[u8]>`
             found enum `Option<&[u8; 32]>`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A slice isn't just a pointer over an array. It's both the pointer to the data and a length (see [Arrays and Slices](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/primitives/array.html)) as it refers to only a part of the array. This is why the types aren't compatible.

What you want here is a slice over the whole array, which you get with the `..` [full range expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/range-expr.html): `slice = &array[..]`.

Having an option, you can conditionally apply this transformation using [map](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map).

Combining all this:

```rust
fn fun_two(x: Option<&Foo>) {
    fun_one(x.map(|a| &a[..]))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind explaining a bit your solution?